# Is there any limit on number of ports at which HAProxy can listen?

Tags: haproxy

I want to configure a HAPRoxy that can listen on 200 ports. Is there any limit on number of ports it can bind to? Also, will there be any performance degradation if it is listening on 200 ports?

Answer (score 4):

According to the official HAProxy [documentation](https://www.haproxy.org/download/2.4/doc/configuration.txt) , the frontend has no limits for the addresses and ports it listens to.

```
  It is possible to specify a list of address:port combinations delimited by
  commas. The frontend will then listen on all of these addresses. There is no
  fixed limit to the number of addresses and ports which can be listened on in
  a frontend, as well as there is no limit to the number of "bind" statements
  in a frontend.
```

According to the latest [benchmarks](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-forwards-over-2-million-http-requests-per-second-on-a-single-aws-arm-instance/) of HAProxy 2.4, the reported number of connections per second is in the range of 2.04 to 2.05 million. This figure was obtained on a system of 46 allocated CPUs, where HAProxy used 42 out of 46.
In your case, it is worth paying more attention to the operating system, RAM and CPU, rather than internal haproxy limits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!